# Можно ли изменить направление recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

Стандартное направление recyclerview это сверху-вниз. Т.е. первые посты вверху, и по умолчанию они сразу же и отображаются на экране. А мне нужно, чтобы порядок был снизу-вверх. Т.е. первые элементы внизу, и отображаются изначально они, а потом уже пользователь листает и сверху вниз выплывают остальные элементы списка.

Возможно ли так сделать? Может там где-то есть настройка?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можете попробовать сделать реверс и задать начало от конца:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter; 
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

..onCreate...{

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: У меня почему-то нет такого метода у LinearLayoutManager

Comment: Всё понял) У меня RecyclerView.LayoutManager было, а надо было LinearLayoutManager. Теперь всё работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Изменить направление можно с помощью

```
LinearLayoutManager#setReverseLayout()
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)

Comment: То же будет справедливо для любого LayoutManager, не только для LinearLayoutManager.