# Как инверсировать список RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть коллекция ArrayList которую я отображаю в RecyclerView. 
Items это карточки с большим количеством визуальных полей "10-15". Мне нужно отображать данные не сверху вниз, а снизу вверх. то есть чтобы последний элемент списка был первым виджетом в списке.
Проблема в том что если я добавляю элемент в начало списка то коллекция перезаписывается и на экране происходит довольно ощутимое мигание виджетов, а хотелось бы чтобы было плавно. Возможно есть готовая функция в адаптере? Либо как то намудрить с позицией? Либо же коллекцию какую то другую выбрать для такого нужно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700265/177345

Comment: Шикарно. работает. спасибо большое!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли изменить направление recyclerview?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700265/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-recyclerview)